# Let there be parallelogram $ABCD$ and point $E$ in $AD$. $F$ is the intersection of $BE$ and $AC$. Show that $\frac{AE}{AD}=\frac{AF}{CF}$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**Problem:**

Let there be parallelogram $ABCD$ and point $E$ in $AD$. F is the intersection of $BE$ and $AC$.

Show that $\frac{AE}{AD}=\frac{AF}{CF}$.

If

I've tried to extend $BE$ so that it intersects $CD$ in $G$ but I think that's not enough. I've also played with the different angles but haven't gotten anything sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $AE||BC$, $\implies$ $\triangle{BFC}\sim\triangle{AFE}$, $\implies$ $\frac{AE}{BC}=\frac{AF}{CF}$, but we know that $BC=AD$ because of $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, $\implies$ $\frac{AE}{AD}=\frac{AF}{CF}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Triangles $\triangle AEF$ and $\triangle CBF$ are similar. Also, $AD=BC$.